# Search result: Show documents and links, but not url to library views

Tags: search, search-results

We have a customer that requested us to show only documents (word, excel, pdf) in search results. We removed all other file types in search, and that worked ok after a while.

However, now they also wants to show links from "link list". But when we allow links, also all the views for all document libraries show up in the search results.

So we get [example]: http://intranet.customer.com/allitems.aspx, http://intranet.customer.com/mydocuments.aspx etc. showing up

Is there any way to index and display link-items from link lists, without also displaying the addresses of views in SharePoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to set a scope rule to achieve this:

1. Follow the directions on [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms546985%28v=office.14%29.aspx) to show raw XML data on search page
2. Look for contentclass of an item that you want to exclude.  Some forums say use STS_List_GenericList, but that did not work for me.  One particular search page I was troubleshooting used STS_List_CustomGrid instead.
3. Within the scopes section of Central Administration or on Site Settings, set a property exclusion scope rule for your undesired contentclass.
4. Either let the scope refresh or push a refresh on Search Administration landing page in Central Administration.
5. Edit core results webpart to use local visualization to reset to default settings
6. Test results in query

This worked for me perfectly.  Good luck!